# How to write such query?

Tags: mysql, sql

How do you programming in SQL, I don't understand nothing in it. :)

Table1:

```
+-----------+----------+------------+
| id        | key      | page       |
+-----------+----------+------------+
| 1         | A        | 123        |
| 2         | B        | 456        |
| 3         | C        | 777        |
+-----------+----------+------------+
```

Table2:

```
+-----------+----------+------------+
| id        | key      | page       |
+-----------+----------+------------+
| 1         | A        | 123        |
| 2         | B        | 456        |
| 3         | C        | 111        |
+-----------+----------+------------+
```

I have 2 tables. We can see that they have fields with the same 'key' (A, B, C). How can I filter 'page' column's value which are differ in Table1 and Table2.

So, in page column: 
`123=123, 456=456, 777<>111`  ==> I want such table as Result:

NEW Table:

```
+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id        | id & page_table1    | id & page_table2    |
+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 1         | 3   777             | 3    111            |
+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM tab1 JOIN tab2 ON tab1.key = tab2.key WHERE tab1.page <> tab2.page`

Comment: @LukaszSzozda ok, let me try this solution.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda Exact what I was needed. Could you please to write an answer for I mark it green? Thank you for your support! You have learned me a lot today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is not "such difficult". First you need to join both tables on `key` column and then filter using `page` column:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tab1 
JOIN tab2 ON tab1.`key` = tab2.`key`
WHERE tab1.page <> tab2.page;
```

Answer (score 2):

@LukazSzozda's comment seems to be the right answer. But if you actually want exactly those three comments in the result, you can concatenate them with the concat function, like this

```
select a.id,
       concat(a.id, ' ', a.page)
       concat(b.id, ' ', b.page),
from Table1 a
join Table2 b
     on a.id = b.id
     and a.key = b.key
where a.page != b.page
```

Comment: Thank you very much for a support!

Answer (score 1):

If you want new table with new ID, you need to have `create table`. I recommend different format

```
CREATE TABLE newTable (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  oldId int NOT NULL,
  tbl1Page int,
  tbl2Page int,
  PRIMARY KEY (id))


INSERT INTO newTable (oldId, tbl1Page, tbl2Page)
SELECT t1.key, t1.Page, t2.Page 
FROM tab1 t1 INNER JOIN 
     tab2 t2 ON t1.key = t2.key 
WHERE t1.page <> t2.page
```

I don't recommend combining ID and Page (or any other 2 data pieces) into one column. You can always combine data when you query it. Read about data normalization

```
Select concat(f1, ' - ', f2) as combinedData . . .
```

Comment: Appreciate your support and such beautiful detailed answer.